# Problem with setting up gurobi with OR-tools

Tags: gurobi, or-tools

I am trying to setup Gurobi with Google OR-Tools with the function `pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("GUROBI")`. The function returns None, which could occur if Gurobi was not linked in, or if the Gurobi license is not supplied.

Currently, `CreateSolver` works with SCIP, and I could run Gurobi through the `gurobipy` interface (I have the licenses set up correctly).

I am using or-tools installed from pip (`pip install ortools`).  Based on online documentation, the binary version of or-tools has support for Gurobi. I would like to know if there are any additional steps I need to take to set up or-tools, or if I must follow a set of instructions to compile or-tools from source to support Gurobi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the binary package locally, with a correct license.

It should pick it up at this point.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by installing the binary package locally?

Comment: Get the official package from the gurobi site.

Comment: I reinstalled gurobi - and or-tools does not pick it up. Are there any debug logs for ortools to output? I would like to know what kind of errors are propping up.

Comment: I reinstalled both packages - and now both are working. Thank you!